# How can I group some rows in SQL and show a count?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this SQL in a SQL Server database:

```
SELECT   E.CreatedDate AS CreatedDate,
         E.ExamId   AS ExamId,
         E.SubjectId As SubjectId,
         E.Title    AS Name,
         E.Text     AS Text,
         E.ExamTypeId AS ExamTypeId
FROM     AdminTest A, 
         Exam E
WHERE    A.ExamId = E.ExamId
AND      A.TestStatusId = 3
```

Can someone tell me can I make it so that it shows a count of the number of AdminTests for each Exam. Right now it returns this:

```
2014-09-27 06:08:43.673 2322        1           Custom Exam 1                                      asfdsadfsadf                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     3
2013-08-22 15:16:00.000 1           1           Exam 1                                             sdfsdf                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           1
2013-08-22 15:16:00.000 1           1           Exam 1                                             sdfsdf                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           1
2013-08-22 15:16:00.000 1           1           Exam 1                                             sdfsdf                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           1
```

What I would like is to see two rows and a column at the end of each showing a 1 and then 3 for this data.

Comment: Add a `COUNT(*) as AdminTests` in the SELECT and a a GROUP BY all the other columns at the end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `group by` and `count` aggregate function:

```
SELECT E.CreatedDate AS CreatedDate,
       E.ExamId   AS ExamId,
       E.SubjectId As SubjectId,
       E.Title    AS Name,
       E.Text     AS Text,
       E.ExamTypeId AS ExamTypeId,
       COUNT(*) AS TotalCount
FROM     AdminTest A 
JOIN     Exam E ON A.ExamId = E.ExamId
WHERE    A.TestStatusId = 3
GROUP BY E.CreatedDate,
         E.ExamId,
         E.SubjectId,
         E.Title,
         E.Text,
         E.ExamTypeId
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for the `GROUP BY` clause :

```
SELECT   
    COUNT(*),
    E.ExamId   AS ExamId
FROM     AdminTest A, 
         Exam E
WHERE    A.ExamId = E.ExamId
AND      A.TestStatusId = 3
GROUP BY ExamId;
```